# Closed out old 401k. Rollover and cash out option. Received wrong amounts

Tags: united-states, 401k, rollover, cash, mistakes

I decided to cash out and rollover my old 401k. I requested a check for some amount after the taxes, and the rest be rolled over into my new 401k.

However, instead I received 3 checks: 2 of which were for my rollover, and only 1 was to me. Problem is that the amounts are all wrong. I only received a very small amount for the cash out and almost all of total amount of the old 401k was written to my new 401k company.

I haven't done anything with the checks yet. Is there anything I can do to get the correct amounts that I wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Try to contact the 401k manager and tell them to place a stop payment on the checks because they were issued for the wrong amounts. If it was their mistake they are required to correct it if you provided the right instructions.

If that doesn't work, you may have 60 days to return the funds back to your plan manager as a 60 day rollover. Not all plans allow it so check to make sure.